Почему стоят запетые?
У неё длинные, волнистые волосы, которые блестят на солнце и красиво обрамляют её лицо, придавая ей нежный и романтичный вид.

У неё длинные волнистые волосы, которые блестят на солнце и красиво обрамляют её лицо, придавая ей нежный и романтичный вид.
Длинные волнистые волосы — неоднородные определения, запятая между ними не ставится.
